# C array problems... (Printing and defining)

Tags: c, arrays, printf

Just writing some code to sort an array using bubble sort, but right at the start I couldn't even define an array and print it.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()  {

int test[] = {9,9,9,9,9};       //define array

test[2] = 3;

bool checker = false;           //is it sorted?

int i = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<=4; i++)                   //set random numbers for array
{
    int g;
    g = 4+i;
    test[i] = g;
    i++;
}

for (int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i )   //print array as normal
{

    printf(", ", test[i]);

}
```

When executed it always outputs:

```
, , , ,
```

so the array is empty? or im printing it wrong? or something?

Comment: You are incrementing with `i++` twice - once in the for statement and once in the body. This is bad...

Comment: Btw. it is a good habit to write the for cycle like this: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)` notice the number 5 rather than 4 so you can immediately see the number of elements and you do not have to subtract 1 in your head and always prefer preincrement `++i` (and other prefix operators) over postincrement `i++` (or other postfix operators). The reason is performance - postfix causes temporary copy to be created in some cases.

Comment: An array can't be empty - it always contains the same amount of things. Your problem is caused primarily by not finding out how `printf` works before using it.

Comment: @V.K. Performance is not a reason for any of the basic types (like `int`), but only for user-defined ones (in some cases). `++i`, `i++`, `i += 1` will all create the same code, at least once optimizations are enabled. Sticking with one or the other is good style though and since it can make a difference for user-defined types, one should stick to `++i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing it wrong.

The line in which you are printing should read `printf("%d, ", test[i]);`

Also not that you have tagged the question as C++, but are using C related terms. Your `#include <stdio.h>` should be replaced by `#include <iostream>` and you should be using `cout` instead of `printf` for outputting data.

Comment: As an aside, using the C standard-library facilities in C++ is perfectly fine (sometimes the C library is superior. Or at least superior in one aspect, like internationalization). Even if the code is written in C-style, if it's compiled as C++, it is C++.

Comment: True that. But I just mentioned it because I felt that the OP may not be aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code.

First, the initial 'for' loop uses 'i' as its counter variable, and your increment condition is 'i++'. That means 'i' automatically increments through each loop iteration; yet within the loop, you specify 'i++', meaning you will see the value of 'i' bumped *twice* with each pass. Eliminate the extraneous increment.

Second, you are printing the array incorrectly. You need to add a format qualifier such as '%d' to tell printf to use the first argument as a replacement for that specifier.

Lastly, you've indicated C++ for this code, but it really isn't. It's classic C.